# MongoDB is not installed correctly in Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

Specs: Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx server, Vestacp control panel.

MongoDB was pre-installed in my server, in 3.6.3 version. It was working but I wanted to upgrade it to version 4.4 (current release).

The problem now is that I can't start the mongo service (community edition).

Steps I followed so far:

Stop MongoDB service, Remove packages and remove Data Directories.

```
sudo service mongod stop

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*

sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

Trying to install the new version 4.4 the exact steps from the documentation. Below are the commands with an order:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install gnupg

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

ps --no-headers -o comm 1

sudo systemctl start mongod

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable mongod

mongo
```

Errors:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It throws an error:

```
Skipping acquire of configured file 'nginx/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

On the step:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

On the step:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

Directories:

```
/var/lib/mongodb
```

and

```
/var/log/mongodb
```

are not auto-created after the installation and I can't find them on the above paths.

The port I am trying to begin the server is the default 27017 and I set the rules to ufw.

I am tried to find a solution from similar posts but nothing. I'm stuck for two days now.
Any thought or help?

Comment: Add complete output of all of commands you executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in uninstallation of previous MongoDB version 3.6.3.

The command in terminal...

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

...Doesn't uninstall all the packages correctly.

The correct uninstallation was to type in the command line:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep mongo
```

...In order to see if there are any packages left from MongoDB. I had 2 packages left that "purge mongodb-org*" couldn't delete.

**So the correct removing executions are the below:**

```
sudo apt remove mongodb
sudo apt purge mongodb
sudo apt autoremove
```

After that, the installation of the new MongoDB version 4.4 was successfully completed without errors!